# do_action(), iFrame Gets Displayed Despite Password Protection

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and Content Protector plugins in trying to protect an iframe for eventbrite ticket registration that gets displayed through Event Calendar plugin. I believe I'm wrapping the part that displayed the iframe with the Content Protector shortcode, but it gets displayed anyway even before entering the password. How could I make it so the iframe is displayed only when the password is entered?

```
<?php
  $password = get_post_custom_values('password');

  if(!empty($password)){
  echo do_shortcode("[content_protector password=". "'".$password[0]."']". do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_meta' ). "[/content_protector]");
  } else {
    do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_meta' );
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`do_action` does not return text, it just does the action. So, calling `do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_meta' )` in your `do_shortcode` call there will cause the iframe to be output before the shortcode.

Comment: I guess what I'm really wondering is how to make it so the code displays the iframe only when the password is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Otto, you need to *capture* the output from the action, and then pass it through the shortcode:

```
ob_start();
do_action( 'tribe_events_single_event_after_the_meta' );
$calendar = ob_get_clean();

$password = get_post_custom_values( 'password' );

if( ! empty( $password ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode( "[content_protector password='{$password[0]}']{$calendar}[/content_protector]" );
} else {
    echo $calendar;
}
```